# Creating and consuming a REST web in Objective-C

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, rest

I have created small application on iOS and have worked on web-services in .Net. However,  I am new to both REST and consuming services in Objective C (REST and SOAP both).

I need your guidance in creating a basic REST web service ( if possible in .Net ) and consuming it Objective C for iPhone application.

I would appreciate if you direct me to text/video tutorials in these two regards.

Your suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
Ajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did an iPhone project hitting a REST service.  To consume, try [asihttprequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).  Very good and used by many other apps.

How to use it ([examples](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use))